# Convert PHP Function to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
function toconv(string)
{
    $gogo = array("a" => "b","cd" => "e");
    $string = str_replace(
        array_keys( $gogo ),
        array_values( $gogo ),
        $string
    );
    return $string;
}
?>
```

How can I implement that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And to make it in a way, where you can do it directly from an array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toconv(string){
    var gogo = {"a":"b", "cd":"e"}, reg;
    for(x in gogo) {
        reg = new RegExp(x, "g");
        string.replace(x, gogo[x]);
    }
    return string;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, nickf, I clearly missed the return-value !-)

Answer (score 2):

String.replace() in Javascript receives regexes instead of strings and here's a translation. You need to append the g modifier to the regex to replace all occurrences instead of only the first one.

```
<script>
function toconv(str) {
    replacements = ['b','e'];
    regexes = [/a/g,/cd/g];

    for (i=0; i < regexes.length; i++) {
       str = str.replace(regexes[i],replacements[i]);
    }
    return str;
}

alert(toconv('acdacd'));
alert(toconv('foobar'));
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert PHP Function to JavaScript

```
if (preg_match('/0/', $check) || preg_match('/1/', $check) || preg_match('/2/', $check) || preg_match('/3/', $check) || preg_match('/4/', $check) || preg_match('/5/', $check) || preg_match('/6/', $check) || preg_match('/7/', $check) || preg_match('/8/', $check) || preg_match('/9/', $check))
{
    exception("personal info not allowed");
    redirect(base_url() . 'edit_profile');
}
else if ((preg_match("~\b@\b~",$check)) || (preg_match("~\b.net\b~",$check)) || (preg_match("~\b.com\b~",$check)) || (preg_match("~\b@\b~",$check)) || (preg_match("~\b.edu\b~",$check)) || (preg_match("~\b.gov\b~",$check)))
{
    exception("personal info not allowed");
    redirect(base_url() . 'edit_profile');
}
```